# how to edit a default navigation bar

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, uinavigationbar

So a noob question: I started a project with a navigation bar in Xamarin and I just want to change the default icons and change names under them in accordance with my app. Can I do that in the constructor view? The buttons themselves already do what I want them to do but I just want to change their appearance. [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmCLc.png) activity_main.xml just in case:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerTwo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/navigation" />
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"
            android:accessibilityHeading="true"
        />
    
        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What specifically do you want to change.

Comment: Hey there again, Jason. I'd like to change a home button to Tv button. Make an icon of a small tv and TV text under it, for example.

Comment: you're right, somehow I brushed this article off as irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it. What I managed to do:

- Used this [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/exploring-androids-bottom-navigation-view/)
- Installed Xamarin.Android.Support.Design
- Downloaded desired icons from [Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)
- Unpacked zip file with icons and placed all of the "drawable" folders in Resources\drawable
- changed android:icon parameter in navigaton.xml to one of the downloaded icon names

NOTE: sometimes preview gets messed up, for example it might size icons in different scales but when you emulate the build or execute it on a real phone everything looks fine.